# Syntax using JS Library to make Repeatable field JSON null

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a repeatable field that based on a switch, when off, I would like to send the DB a null value for the entire field.

I am using the JS Library to achieve this and am able to change the values for the rows within the repeatable field before saving, but not the overall JSON object.

I have tried variations of:

```
crud.field('repeatable_field_parent').input.value)
crud.field('repeatable_field_parent').value)
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Backpack does not provide a way to change the value of the *entire* repeatable field. But you should be able to use custom JS for that.

The repeatable field has an element that stores all the names of the subfields. You can use that, then loop through all subfields to disable them. So:

```js
crud.field('visible').onChange(field => {
    var subfields = $(crud.field('repeatable').input).parent().find('[data-repeatable-holder]').data('subfield-names');

    // disable/enable all subfields
    subfields.forEach(element => {
        crud.field('repeatable').subfield(element).enable(field.value == 1);
    });

    // hide/show the repeatable entirely
    crud.field('repetable').show(field.value == 1);
}).change(); 
// this last change() call makes the code above also run on pageload, 
// so that if the checkbox starts checked, it's visible,
// if the checkbox starts unchecked, it's hidden
```

Comment: Yes, definitely coming at it from a usability aspect. The switch shows/hides the entire repeatable block. When it's shown, it should save exactly as the user sees it. When it's hidden, it should send null as it's the equivalent of the user zeroing out the entire block rather than having to delete each row.

Comment: I am quite new to this... I have tried using child/parent/queryselector and am not seeing where the hidden input lives. Any ideas what structure I should be expecting? Is there a name or ID I could use?

Comment: Oh that's a very valid use case! I tried to do it too... to provide you with some example code, and I discovered I was wrong. There is no hidden input in the current version of Backpack. I mean there is, but it won't store any value. You have to go through all subfields and clear them individually. Which... we don't have an API for ‍♂️ I've added https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/422 to create this feature.

Comment: I've updated my answer with working custom code, until we create that functionality!

Comment: You're a legend!!! Thanks so much

Comment: oddly enough custom code only allows you to disable the field. When trying to change the input value it does not work for me. I ended up doing this instead:           for (let i = 1; i <= crud.field('featured_posts').wrapper.find('.repeatable-element').length; i++) {
               crud.field('featured_posts').subfield('select_from_array',i).input.value = 0;
}

Comment: Hmm the reason I chose to disable the fields was that… because disabled HTML fields no longer pass their value, they’re ignored. So it’s just as if they were null, right? I thought it would be a more elegant solution to the same problem but if what you need is to have them NULL, have at it!

Comment: aaah... that makes sense. The only issue with that is if the user had saved the repeatable fields with values and then toggles the switch off and saves again. Then it won't zero the old values out. At least that's what I was seeing when I was testing with it. Appreciate your help no end. Thanks so much for taking the time. HERO!